# T-Sql search by hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server.

I have a table Groups with two integer columns:

```
MEGR_KEY
MEGR_KEY1
```

`MEGR_KEY` is primary key of group. Each group can have sub groups.

For example - I have a group 1195:

`MEGR_KEY` = 1195

There are subgroups of 1195:

```
MEGR_KEY = 9484    
MEGR_KEY1 = 1195
```

and

```
MEGR_KEY = 7494
MEGR_KEY1 = 1195
```

Basically `MEGR_KEY1` is telling, which group is a parent.

The problem I have is, how to find all `MEGR_KEY` subgroups hierarchically, given only root group name? Let's say (from previous example) there is 1195 root group. There are already two subgroups: 7494 and 9484. Now, those two subgroups can also be parent groups to some other groups. So, I have to find rows where `MEGR_KEY1` = 7494 OR `MEGR_KEY1` = 9484. How to find all subgroups if group number (MEGR_KEY) is given? I have a problem here writing query for this.

Comment: Take a look at recursive self-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case lets build schema

```
    CREATE TABLE #TAB (MEGR_KEY INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), MEGR_KEY1 INT)

    INSERT INTO #TAB
    SELECT 19 , 'Name1'   , 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 ,'Name2'   , 19
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 , 'Name3'   , 20
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 22 , 'Name4'  , 21
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 , 'Name5'  , 21
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 26 , 'Name6'  , 19
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 28 , 'Name7'  , 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 29 , 'Name7'  , 18
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 , 'Name8'  , 18
```

Now Query the Table (I took a CTE recursively)

```
    DECLARE @MEGR_KEY INT=19;

    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  * FROM #TAB WHERE MEGR_KEY= @MEGR_KEY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.* FROM #TAB T 
    INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.MEGR_KEY1 = C.MEGR_KEY
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE
```

And the result will be

[image]